# Como puedo remplazar varios textos usando Replace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv, str-replace

Estoy buscando replazar varios strings y despues escribirlos en un archivo .csv

Todo me funciona bien cuando remplazo un solor texto, pero al querer remplazar 2 o mas solo me toma el ultimo texto de remplazo lo cual solo se me permite poner un string despues de `WriteAllText`.

Este es mi codigo:

```
string reemplazo = "";
string reemplazo2 = "";

string Arch = File.ReadAllText(originalFileName); //Aqui leo mi archivo .csv
reemplazo = Regex.Replace(Arch, @"&#x2F;", @"/");
reemplazo2 = Regex.Replace(Arch, @"&ndash;", @"-");

File.WriteAllText(newFileName.Substring(0, newFileName.Length - 4) + "Test.csv", reemplazo); //solo puedo poner un valor del remplazo

File.Move(originalFileName, newFileName);

files.Add(newFileName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.. tenes un problema bastante simple, y es que no estas reemplazando el texto sobre el string que acabas de usar, si no siempre sobre el original, por lo cual, el texto que queda es solo el del ultimo reemplazo.

```
//Obtenemos todo el string
string Arch = File.ReadAllText(originalFileName); //Aqui leo mi archivo .csv
//reemplazamos sobre Arch
reemplazo = Regex.Replace(Arch, @"&#x2F;", @"/");
//reemplazamos sobre Arch, otra vez :(
reemplazo2 = Regex.Replace(Arch, @"&ndash;", @"-");
```

En realidad, reemplazo2 deberia ser:

```
//tenemos que reemplazar, sobre reemplazo!!!!!
reemplazo2 = Regex.Replace(reemplazo , @"&ndash;", @"-");
```

Replace reemplaza en una cadena, y devuelve otra cadena distinta con los reemplazos hechos. por lo tanto, el proximo replace, debe si o si usar esa nueva cadena.

Como nota, podrias hacer replace y mandar el contenido a la misma cadena sin problemas:

```
//Esto es valido tambien!
string Arch = File.ReadAllText(originalFileName); //Aqui leo mi archivo .csv
Arch = Regex.Replace(Arch, @"&#x2F;", @"/");
Arch = Regex.Replace(Arch, @"&ndash;", @"-");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tenias razon,aplique los cambios como me recomiendas en la ultima parte y funciona perfectamente. Saludos!